# html input date restrict dates on the second input date depend on the first date

Tags: html

I need a little help from html input dates :

```
<input type ="date" name="FromDate">
<input type ="date" name="ToDate">
```

My agenda is I want to output the second date based on selected first date

For Example :

On the first date, I select January 19 , from there it will restrict to 14 days  on the second date and I can only select until Feb 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable you can use the following.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
```

body:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  });
});
</script>
```

[image]